# Python-like function decorators in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement a Python-like function decorator in C using function pointers but I'm getting weird segmentation fault error.

Idea is that we have a **decorator** function which has inner function **wrapper**. Decorator then takes **some_function** as an argument, puts it inside the **wrapper** along with additional code and returns the **wrapper** function.

Very simple function decorator in Python:

```
def decorator(f):
  def wrapper():
    #do something before
    f()
    #do something after
  return wrapper

def some_func():
  print('Hello')

some_func = decorator(some_func)
```

I know that Python, unlike C, treats functions as first class objects but I'm wondering if the same sort of functionality can be emulated in C by using **function pointers**.

I tried this

```
void* do_twice(void (*func)())
{
  auto void wrapper()
  { 
    func();
    func(); 
  }

  return &wrapper;
}

void some_func()
{ printf("Hello\n"); }

int main()
{
  void (*fun_ptr)() = &some_func;
  fun_ptr = decorator(fun_ptr);
  fun_ptr();
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Hello
Segmentation fault
```

Now here is the funny bit. If I declare a variable inside **wrapper** like this:

```
  auto void wrapper()
  {
    int blah=5;
    func();
    func();
  }
```

Then segmentation fault is fixed. Can someone explain why is this so? Apparently I'm doing something wrong with the pointers and code is very unstable - seemingly unrelated additions to the main function will cause segmentation fault to pop again.

Comment: This is not C -- there are no nested functions in C.

Comment: GCC has language extension for nested functions. I should have added a disclaimer. Thanks to whoever pointed out that the issue lies in returning memory address of a local variable. That sheds some light on the issue. I suppose compiler is reusing that memory area for other purposes which causes weird behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you allow me to have an excursion to C++? In this language, there are functor objects, these are kind of structs that can be called like a function:

```
 struct Wrapper
 {
     /* this is what allows the struct to be called like a function: */
     void operator()(/* can define arbitrary parameters here */)
     { /* some implementation */ }
 };
```

In other words, this would allow you to write code like:

```
 Wrapper w; // actually, C++ does more here than C, but that's out of
            // scope of this question...
 w(); // possible due to the operator() defined above
```

OK, now let's extend that a bit:

```
 struct Wrapper
 {
     void(*m_f)(void); /* !!! */

     void operator()(void) /* don't want any parameters... */
     {
         printf("before\n");
         m_f();
         printf("after\n");
     }
 };
```

Don't want to go any deeper, a C++ developer would now deal with accessibility (such that the member `m_f` can only be used inside the class) and would provide a so-called constructor (for initialising `m_f` member appropriately). With all that, the final C++ code using the wrapper class might look like:

```
 Wrapper decorate(void(*f)(void))
 {
     return Wrapper(f); // the fore-mentioned constructor gets called    
 }

 void test(void) { /* do something */ }

 void demo(void)
 {
      Wrapper w = decorate(&test);
      w();
 }
```

Why that excursion? Well, have a close look at one specific line:

```
 void(*m_f)(void);
```

Yes, there is a member variable! Python actually does something similar internally.

The 'problem' with C is that you cannot define your own function call operators. There's only the native one. So the big question is: *Where to store the function pointer?*

You could have a struct, storing the function pointer (analogously to the C++ solution), and pass that one to your own function emulating the function call operator. Actually, the C++ solution doesn't do anything else either, solely that all this is hidden behind syntactic sugar!

An equivalent C solution might look like this:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    void(*m_f)(void);
};

void executeDecorated(Wrapper w)
{
    printf("before\n");
    w.m_f();
    printf("after\n");
}

void demo(void)
{
    Wrapper w = { &someFunction };
    executeDecorated(w);
    /* do whatever else ... */
    executeDecorated(w);
}
```

This is probably the closest you can get in C (apart from that you might perhaps find better names).

If having a separate struct to store a function pointer brings you sufficient benefit or if you just want to pass the function pointer directly (`executeDecorated(&someFunction)`, assuming the function was adjusted appropriately) is up to you to decide...

Comment: That was helpful. I will do some experimentation with using struct wrappers.